# How keep spring context loaded between test runs in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, junit

[Spring-test](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) provides annotation for loading spring context during test runs. For example  there is a `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` junit runner class and `org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration` annotation for specify context loading. For integration tests context loading can be quite long and during debugging it is needed to run same test dozen times until it "lose" all it's errors. Is there a way to do so without loading context multiple times? For example I finished debugging context loading, then run that context and start running test in intellij idea? Is that possible with Intellij Idea?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. JUnit will load the context for every new cycle of JUnit.

Comment: You can use Test Suite to club require test cases and execute that test suite

Comment: In case you wanna participate in the discussion https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32686

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago without answer, which is strange, and this is very important to know because it can save a lot of resources and time.

If you have one class with annotation

```
@SpringBootTest
public class IntegrationTest
```

And you extend it to all your Test classes context will be loaded only once

```
public class ServiceIntegationTest extends IntegrationTest
```

All tests in this class will use same context. Also all classes that extend this class will reuse same context.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking. Besides, to get what you're explaining; "All tests in this class will use same context.", you don't have to do anything. Justing using `SpringBootTest` alone would give that. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cleanest solution, but this works just fine.

1. Create a Spring-Boot application in tests which more or less represents the main application (in terms of configurations):

```kotlin
// In a different package from the main application
// The `scanBasePackages` is the same as the main application!
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = ["com.example.api"])
class TestApplication {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic // main method to be able to run it in IDEs
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            runApplication<TestApplication>(*args)
        }
    }
}
```

2. Create another *thin* Spring Boot application in which create and publish  the above application as a bean:

```kotlin
// In a different package from to the above
// Ideally this should almost exclude every Spring configurations
// in the classpath (they should be loaded in the above application)
@SpringBootApplication
class TestApplicationLoader {

    @Value("\${test-subject.context.load:true}")
    private var loadContext = false

    @Bean
    fun testSubject(): Closeable {
        return if (loadContext) {
            val environment = StandardEnvironment()
            val sa = SpringApplication(TestApplication::class.java)
            sa.run()
        } else { // it's loaded by the IDE or Gradle!
            Closeable {}
        }
    }
}
```

3. Finally, add your normal Spring Boot test:

```kotlin
// If you make TestApplicationLoader as thin as possible
// this should take around one second or two to complete!
@SpringBootTest(classes = [TestApplicationLoader::class])
class MyControllerTest : StringSpec() {
    override fun extensions() = listOf(SpringExtension)

    @Autowired
    lateinit var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    init {
        "test" {
            val res = testRestTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/hello", String::class.java)
            res shouldBe "mocked in test-application"
        }
    }
}
```

There's a few things to note/improve with this approach:

1. It requires good discipline in the team with respect to codebase maintenance; where to put integration tests, Spring configurations, beans, etc. You could easily end up with a messed up context with unwanted beans.
2. It's not straightforward how to deal with environments, profiles, and properties.
3. Accessing beans created in the main application context is a challenge. (For example to JDBC data source beans.)
4. What to do with shared resources (e.g. ports) is a (not-so-hard) question.
5. Support for Gradle Continues Build requires a bit of configuration in the build script.

I've created a sample project [here](https://github.com/akefirad/spring-boot-integration-test) as a proof of concept.
(The fact that no one has dealt with this issue is just mind-boggling. Looking forward to official and/or better solutions)