# Keep Spring context running after test suite ends, IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

Here's the story: everytime I want to run one or more integration tests the Spring context needs to start and it takes up to 2 minutes.

This is kind of frustrating becasue after every minimal change I need to wait this time in order to check the test result.

Is there a way I can keep the Spring context running after the tests end, to avoid waiting? Something like starting the Spring application once and then perform tests.

*Update*

Just found a very similar question:
[How keep spring context loaded between test runs in Intellij Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696742/how-keep-spring-context-loaded-between-test-runs-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Are you aware of: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html ? If yes how is your usecase different so the context cannot be reused by default?

Comment: Spring test supports caching of the contexts between test executions by default. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching
unless you have a @DirtiesContext or DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener is used.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this. I'd advise writing a specific configuration or app context XML file just for tests that only loads required classes. I'd also advise asking if whatever your testing really needs Spring context.

Comment: @PraneethRamesh The question is about keeping the Spring Context loaded _after_ the test suite is done.

Comment: Did anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: In case anyone wants to participate in the discussion https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32686

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating my answer from the other question for the sake of completeness:
Probably not the cleanest solution, but this works just fine.

1. Create a Spring-Boot application in tests which more or less represents the main application (in terms of configurations):

```kotlin
// In a different package from the main application
// The `scanBasePackages` is the same as the main application!
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = ["com.example.api"])
class TestApplication {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic // main method to be able to run it in IDEs
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            runApplication<TestApplication>(*args)
        }
    }
}
```

2. Create another *thin* Spring Boot application in which create and publish  the above application as a bean:

```kotlin
// In a different package from to the above
// Ideally this should almost exclude every Spring configurations
// in the classpath (they should be loaded in the above application)
@SpringBootApplication
class TestApplicationLoader {

    @Value("\${test-subject.context.load:true}")
    private var loadContext = false

    @Bean
    fun testSubject(): Closeable {
        return if (loadContext) {
            val environment = StandardEnvironment()
            val sa = SpringApplication(TestApplication::class.java)
            sa.run()
        } else { // it's loaded by the IDE or Gradle!
            Closeable {}
        }
    }
}
```

3. Finally, add your normal Spring Boot test:

```kotlin
// If you make TestApplicationLoader as thin as possible
// this should take around one second or two to complete!
@SpringBootTest(classes = [TestApplicationLoader::class])
class MyControllerTest : StringSpec() {
    override fun extensions() = listOf(SpringExtension)

    @Autowired
    lateinit var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    init {
        "test" {
            val res = testRestTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/hello", String::class.java)
            res shouldBe "mocked in test-application"
        }
    }
}
```

There's a few things to note/improve with this approach:

1. It requires good discipline in the team with respect to codebase maintenance; where to put integration tests, Spring configurations, beans, etc. You could easily end up with a messed up context with unwanted beans.
2. It's not straightforward how to deal with environments, profiles, and properties.
3. Accessing beans created in the main application context is a challenge. (For example to JDBC data source beans.)
4. What to do with shared resources (e.g. ports) is a (not-so-hard) question.
5. Support for Gradle Continues Build requires a bit of configuration in the build script.

I've created a sample project [here](https://github.com/akefirad/spring-boot-integration-test) as a proof of concept.
(The fact that no one has dealt with this issue is just mind-boggling. Looking forward to official and/or better solutions)